Scrapy Spider does not work with multiple urls
I wrote a Scrapy spider and used Selenium in it to scrape the products in devgrossonline.com.
It does not work with multiple category urls, but it works when I provide only one url.
Here is my spider:
import time
from datetime import datetime

import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


class DevgrossSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'devgross'
    allowed_domains = ['devgrossonline.com']
    start_urls = [
        'https://devgrossonline.com/sut-kahvaltilik',
        'https://devgrossonline.com/meyve-sebze',
        'https://devgrossonline.com/et-sarkuteri'
    ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DevgrossSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
        self.driver.maximize_window()

    def closed(self):
        self.driver.quit()

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        time.sleep(5)

        # find how many pages there are
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'ul.pagination'))
        )
        page_count_selector = "ul.pagination li:last-child"
        page_count = self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, page_count_selector).text
        try:
            page_count = int(page_count)
        except:
            page_count = 1

        # page iteration
        for i in range(1, page_count + 1):
            # go next page
            WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'ul.pagination'))
            )
            if i != 1:
                current_page = self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a#secili-sayfa')
                next_page = current_page.find_element(By.XPATH, 'following::li/a[@onclick][1]')
                next_page.click()
                time.sleep(1)

            WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'ul.pagination')))
            WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.urun-kutusu')))
            WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'cat_rw_05')))
            time.sleep(2)

            product_elements = self.driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.urun-kutusu')

            for product_element in product_elements:
                product_name = product_element.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'h2 a').text
                product_price = product_element.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.urun-fiyat span').text
                try:
                    product_price = float(product_price.replace(' TL', '').replace(',', '.'))
                except:
                    product_price = -1.0
                product_url = product_element.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                                                           'div.kutu-urun-resmi a.kutu-link').get_attribute('href')

                yield {
                    'name': product_name,
                    'price': product_price,
                    'URL': product_url,
                    'date': datetime.now(),
                }

The code does not provide consistent results.

What happens instead?

Besides, as this uses almost no Scrapy features except maybe feed exports and pipelines, consider whether you actually want to use it.

@wRAR what happens instead is not deterministic, it sometimes goes all pages of one category, sometimes it does not.

@wRAR also, I don't wanna use it as well but I have to use it since the firm I'm working in as an intern wants it in this way.

If you cannot drop Scrapy and still want to use Selenium you need to switch to scrapy-selenium (and not use time.sleep()).

I would respectfully suggest that you consider using Playwright rather than Selenium with Scrapy. Playwright offers similar functionality to Selenium but, IMHO, the integration with Scrapy is more up to date.
Install these packages:
scrapy-playwright==0.0.34
beautifulsoup4==4.12.3

Use Playwright to install Chrome.
playwright install --force chrome

In settings.py:
DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS = {
    "http": "scrapy_playwright.handler.ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler",
    "https": "scrapy_playwright.handler.ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler",
}
PLAYWRIGHT_DEFAULT_NAVIGATION_TIMEOUT = 30 * 1000
PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSER_TYPE = "chromium"
PLAYWRIGHT_LAUNCH_OPTIONS = {"headless": False}

And a simple spider that opens all three of the initial pages.
import scrapy
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


class DevgrossSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "devgross"
    allowed_domains = ["devgrossonline.com"]
    start_urls = [
        'https://devgrossonline.com/sut-kahvaltilik',
        'https://devgrossonline.com/meyve-sebze',
        'https://devgrossonline.com/et-sarkuteri'
    ]

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url,
                meta=dict(
                    playwright=True,
                    playwright_include_page=True,
                ),
            )

    async def parse(self, response):
        page = response.meta["playwright_page"]

        await page.wait_for_selector("ul.pagination")

        html = await page.content()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

        await page.close()

        products = soup.select("div.urun-kutusu")

        for product in products:
            name = product.select_one("h2 a").string.strip()
            price = product.select_one("div.urun-fiyat span").string.strip()

            yield {
                "name": name,
                "price": price,
            }

That doesn't yet implement pagination. But you can see in the output below that all three start pages are being opened.
2024-07-02 06:09:43 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://devgrossonline.com/sut-kahvaltilik> (referer: None) ['playwright']
2024-07-02 06:09:43 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://devgrossonline.com/sut-kahvaltilik>
{'name': 'VADİM TOST PEYNİRİ 600 GR', 'price': '120,89 TL'}
2024-07-02 06:09:43 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://devgrossonline.com/sut-kahvaltilik>
{'name': 'TAHSİLDAROĞLU ÇEÇİL PEYNİRİ 180 GR', 'price': '87,89 TL'}
2024-07-02 06:09:43 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://devgrossonline.com/sut-kahvaltilik>
{'name': 'TAHSİLDAROĞLU ÖRGÜ PEYNİRİ 180 GR', 'price': '87,89 TL'}
2024-07-02 06:09:43 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://devgrossonline.com/sut-kahvaltilik>
{'name': 'YÖRE YEŞİL ÇİZİK ZEYTİN (351-400) KG', 'price': '153,89 TL'}
2024-07-02 06:09:43 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://devgrossonline.com/sut-kahvaltilik>
{'name': 'SÜTAŞ ÇİLEKLİ SÜT 6X180 ML', 'price': '49,39 TL'}
2024-07-02 06:09:43 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://devgrossonline.com/sut-kahvaltilik>
{'name': 'SÜTAŞ MUZLU SÜT 6X180 ML', 'price': '49,39 TL'}
2024-07-02 06:09:43 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://devgrossonline.com/sut-kahvaltilik>
{'name': 'TORKU TEREYAĞI RULO 750 GR', 'price': '258,39 TL'}
2024-07-02 06:09:43 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://devgrossonline.com/sut-kahvaltilik>
{'name': 'TEMPO FINDIK EZMELİ BAR 24 GR', 'price': '16,39 TL'}
2024-07-02 06:09:43 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://devgrossonline.com/sut-kahvaltilik>
{'name': 'TEMPO ANTEP EZME 24 GR', 'price': '29,59 TL'}
2024-07-02 06:09:43 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://devgrossonline.com/sut-kahvaltilik>
{'name': 'YAYMER PANCAR PEKMEZİ 450 GR', 'price': '87,89 TL'}
2024-07-02 06:09:47 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://devgrossonline.com/meyve-sebze> (referer: None) ['playwright']
2024-07-02 06:09:48 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://devgrossonline.com/meyve-sebze>
{'name': 'KANDEMİR MANTAR 400 GR', 'price': '58,19 TL'}
2024-07-02 06:09:48 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://devgrossonline.com/meyve-sebze>
{'name': 'ZÜMRÜT KUŞ ÜZÜMÜ 40G', 'price': '18,59 TL'}
2024-07-02 06:09:48 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://devgrossonline.com/meyve-sebze>
{'name': 'İĞDE KG', 'price': '164,89 TL'}
2024-07-02 06:09:48 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://devgrossonline.com/meyve-sebze>
{'name': 'SARI ÜZÜM 11 NO KG', 'price': '307,89 TL'}
2024-07-02 06:09:48 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://devgrossonline.com/meyve-sebze>
{'name': 'SİYAH ÜZÜM ÖZEL KG', 'price': '274,89 TL'}
2024-07-02 06:09:48 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://devgrossonline.com/meyve-sebze>
{'name': 'YER ÇİLEĞİ KG', 'price': '247,39 TL'}
2024-07-02 06:09:48 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://devgrossonline.com/meyve-sebze>
{'name': 'YARIM YABAN MERSİNİ KG', 'price': '313,39 TL'}
2024-07-02 06:09:48 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://devgrossonline.com/meyve-sebze>
{'name': 'DOMATES PEMBE KG', 'price': '43,99 TL'}
2024-07-02 06:09:48 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://devgrossonline.com/meyve-sebze>
{'name': 'SOĞAN ARPACIK KG', 'price': '43,99 TL'}
2024-07-02 06:09:48 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://devgrossonline.com/meyve-sebze>
{'name': 'BİBER RENKLİ DOLMA KG', 'price': '43,99 TL'}
2024-07-02 06:09:52 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://devgrossonline.com/et-sarkuteri> (referer: None) ['playwright']
2024-07-02 06:09:52 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://devgrossonline.com/et-sarkuteri>
{'name': 'BANVİT PİLİÇ KOKTEYL SOSİS KÜVET 500 GR', 'price': '63,69 TL'}
2024-07-02 06:09:52 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://devgrossonline.com/et-sarkuteri>
{'name': 'AKDENİZ TOROS PİLİÇ 5 Lİ SOSİS 225 GR', 'price': '65,89 TL'}
2024-07-02 06:09:52 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://devgrossonline.com/et-sarkuteri>
{'name': 'AKDENİZ TOROS PİLİÇ SALAM TOMBİK 250 GR', 'price': '62,59 TL'}
2024-07-02 06:09:52 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://devgrossonline.com/et-sarkuteri>
{'name': 'AKDENİZ TOROS DANA SALAM TOMBİK 250 GR', 'price': '184,69 TL'}
2024-07-02 06:09:52 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://devgrossonline.com/et-sarkuteri>
{'name': 'ŞENPİLİÇ DOYFRAM DİLİMLİ PİLİÇ SUCUK 240 GR', 'price': '53,85 TL'}
2024-07-02 06:09:52 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://devgrossonline.com/et-sarkuteri>
{'name': 'AYTAÇ BATON PİLİÇ SUCUK 300 GR', 'price': '73,59 TL'}
2024-07-02 06:09:52 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://devgrossonline.com/et-sarkuteri>
{'name': 'AKDENİZ TOROS DANA KANGAL SUCUK 200 GR', 'price': '194,59 TL'}
2024-07-02 06:09:52 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://devgrossonline.com/et-sarkuteri>
{'name': 'AKDENİZ TOROS PİLİÇ KANGAL SUCUK 250 GR', 'price': '116,49 TL'}
2024-07-02 06:09:52 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://devgrossonline.com/et-sarkuteri>
{'name': 'ŞENPİLİÇ PİLİÇ SALAM 200GR', 'price': '22,55 TL'}
2024-07-02 06:09:52 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://devgrossonline.com/et-sarkuteri>
{'name': 'NAMET DANA SUCUK 300GR', 'price': '153,89 TL'}


Now it really looks like a clean code, thank you sir! But I have several questions, and a problem. I started a project with
scrapy startproject devgross' exactly did what you said, and executed it with  scrapy crawl devgross -o products.json in the project directory (same level as .cfg file), but it did not work. it printed those kind of  errors:AttributeError: 'PipeTransport' object has no attribute '_output' AttributeError: 'ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler' object has no attribute 'browser_type' NotImplementedError`

I also wonder why do you use bs4 despite being able to scrape with Scrapy?

I use bs4 out of habit.

Please add full backtrace for those errors to your original question. Easier to debug when I can see the context of the errors.

Only 0.0.36+ runs on Windows.
